# How to write custom footer for some pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using `fancyhdr` to hide header and footer in some pages but I also want to write custom footers for certain pages. Is there an easy way to do it?

Or is there any way to put define text in the center of footer?

I am using XeTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you describe your wishes more precisely, e.g. via a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  There are at least two ways to do this: (1) change pagestyle for the given page or (2) use the mark mechanisms described in the fancyhdr documentation.  Which is more appropriate depends on how the changes in the footer are to be triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a standard way to do so in `fancyhdr`, however, I added something like "copy `{fancy}` style into `{footmark}` style" so that you don't have to change everything:

```
\makeatletter
% new style {footmark}
\fancypagestyle{footmark}{
  \ps@@fancy % use {fancy} style as a base of {footmark}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\footmark}
}
% sets value of \footmark and sets the correct style for this page only
\newcommand\markfoot[1]{\gdef\footmark{#1}\thispagestyle{footmark}}
\makeatother
```

And in the document, in a text that is on the page, you say:

```
\markfoot{This is foot text.}
```

This should print `This is foot text.` centered in the footer of the current page.

Comment: @user25118 that's a non-sense. Then you want probably something completely different and you ought to specify the question.

Comment: the problem in this solution that I need to define tens of new styles in preamble to accommodate my needs. I want something like \thispagestyle command. It may be called  \thisfancyfoot command.

Comment: Now, there's the `\footmark` command that prints its argument in footer and on current page only.