# Custom footer without number of pages

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I use `fancyhdr` to create a custom footer in the left,I refer to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95676/28802) so I use

```
\makeatletter
% new style {footmark}
\fancypagestyle{footmark}{
  \ps@@fancy % use {fancy} style as a base of {footmark}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\footmark}
}
% sets value of \footmark and sets the correct style for this page only
\newcommand\markfoot[1]{\gdef\footmark{#1}\thispagestyle{footmark}}
\makeatother
```

And in the document, in a text that is on the page:

```
\markfoot{Mon texte.}
```

This should print `Mon texte.` left in the footer of the current page. But it display number of page too. how can I do to hide it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, make a Minimal Working Example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want page numbers in the footer, you have to add `\fancyhf{}` to clear all history :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
% new style {footmark}
\fancypagestyle{footmark}{
  \ps@@fancy % use {fancy} style as a base of {footmark}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{\footmark}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
}
% sets value of \footmark and sets the correct style for this page only
\newcommand\markfoot[1]{\gdef\footmark{#1}\thispagestyle{footmark}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  Some text \markfoot{Mon texte.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why base it on the `fancy` pagestyle at all in this case? Why not just omit that line and the need for `\makeatletter` altogether? Would the result differ? Or would the code just be simpler? I'm not sure about this - does the fancy pagestyle set up anything beyond the commands set to mark the headers and footers and draw the foot and headrules?

Comment: @cfr I have no idea!. I was just addressing to the OP's problem :) May be without `fancyhdr` it can be done more simpler.

Comment: Thanks a lot thats what i need thanks @Harish_Kumar and all